# How to add system.text.json into Powershell?

Tags: powershell, system.text.json

How can I install the system.text.json namespace into powershell 5?
I have a standard Windows 11 computer with .NET framework 4.8.1 installed. I need this to convert a large JSON-string into a datatable.

After some more troubleshooting it looks like I need to install Nuget as a new PackageSource first:

```
Install-PackageProvider Nuget –force    
$null = Register-PackageSource -Name 'NuGet' -Location 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2' -ProviderName 'NuGet'
```

But when I try to install System.Text.Json as a package via this command:

```
install-package System.Text.Json
```

then I get an error saying "Dependency loop detected for package 'System.Text.Json'."

Next, I iwas testing this command and it looks like the module is now installed:

```
Install-Package System.Text.Json -Source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2 -SkipDependencies
```

but when I try to write any PS-code the auto-complete in PS is not showing any objects/methods for [system.text.json]. Whats wrong?

Comment: It comes with powershell 7.  It may not be compatible with 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Install-Package`

```
Install-Package System.Text.Json -Version 5.0.2
```

Comment: PS tells me that there is no known parameter "version" and without that info it tells me that it canot find a package with that name.

Comment: see the original link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json - check your powershell version

Comment: the abve link tells me, that .net framework 4.6.2 or higher is required. I have 4.8 and PS 5.1. PackageSource I have installed is the default "PSGallery". Do I need to add another source?